# Query to list table with column name and Data but instead of column name need business column name from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have few tables one of them is Employee table with columns eid,ename,sal,deptno. When i write a query

```
select * from employee
```

output is :

```
eid ename   sal deptno
1   Amit    10000   10
2   Alice   20000   20
3   Bob 12000   15
```

But I want some business Name like (Employee Identifier, Employee name, Employee Sal, Employee Department Number) instead of physical column names that to without using alias. I have already stored business column name in some table like metadata_rename table.

```
Metadata_rename table.
----------------------------------------------------------------
DBname  tablename   ColumnName  BusinessColumnName
----------------------------------------------------------------
dbo       emp         ID           Identifier
dbo       emp         FirstName    First Name
dbo       emp         LastName     Last Name
dbo       employee    eid          Employee Identifier
dbo       employee    ename        Employee Name
dbo       employee    sal          Employee Salary
dbo       employee    deptno       Employee Depatment Number
```

In real time tables are more and columns are also 100-150 so alias is not a good option. can we it dynamically.

Instead of this we can pass parameters and all.

Expected output:
select eid from employee;

---

### Employee Name

Amit
Alice
Bob

```
Select * from employee;
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Employee Identifier    Employee Name   Employee Salary   Employee Dept. Number
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    Amit                10000          10
2                    Alice               20000          20
3                    Bob                 12000          15
```

Comment: in power Bi while generating reports physical name is coming in report, we want business name without underscore and all. right now we are dealing using manual change or alias but we want to dynamically do this, so when we pull data business name + data will come.

Answer (score 0):

I generally think this is a horrible idea, but the concept intrigued me.  This absolutely does work -- I tried it.  You would need to extend it another layer to add database name.

```
DECLARE @tableName AS VARCHAR(64) = 'employee'

DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(1024) = (
    'SELECT ' + STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + s.COLUMN_NAME + ' AS [' + ISNULL(a.BusinessColumnName, s.COLUMN_NAME) + ']'
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS s
        LEFT JOIN Metadata_rename AS a ON a.ColumnName = s.COLUMN_NAME
        WHERE s.TABLE_NAME = @tableName
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
    ) + ' FROM ' + @tableName
 EXEC (@query)
```